# Customization of TTL in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, ttl

We're using Cassandra to store logs. Our data access pattern looks like a queue - there is a process that writes logs to Cassandra and there is a process that reads and analyzes them. If everything goes smoothly, logs are read out of Cassandra with 15 minutes delay and can be deleted after that - so, it is possible use TTL capability to efficiently cleanup the obsolete logs in Cassandra.

However, if the reading process fails or whatever, it is necessary to suspend automatic cleanup in order to prevent data loss. **Is there way to switch TTL on/off globally and dynamically or customize TTL process somehow (hook into compaction, set custom cleanup condition instead of a timestamp, etc)?**

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying that you rely on TTL to clean up after the logs are analyzed, instead of having the analyzer process consume them?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not a way to have TTL processing suspended.  You need to issue deletes from the consumer, or have longer TTL's that you are sure you can process the data in time, even if there is a failure.